# Display first records in a sorted Map

Tags: java, dictionary, sortedmap

I'm trying to display first 40 records out of 17K I have stored in a map. I have the following code

```
import java.util.*;
Map<String, Integer> doubleCount= new HashMap<String,Integer>(); 
....
Map<String,Integer> newDouble40 = doubleCount.headMap(40);
```

Java is giving me the following error:

```
" cannot find symbol - method subMap...
```

so I tried:

```
Map<String,Integer> newDouble40 = doubleCount.subMap("",(Integer)40);
```

and the exact error was:
    cannot find symbol - method subMap(java.lang.String,java.lang.int)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html
how do I sort?

Comment: `subMap` is a method of `SortedMap` but your `doubleCount` object has the abstract `Map` interface as its static type and the also unsorted `HashMap` as dynamic type.  So, use a `SortedMap` in the first place if you need one.

Answer (score 4):

`subMap()` and `headMap()` are two methods in [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) those are not available in `Map`

You can try following way

```
 Map<String, Integer> doubleCount= new HashMap<String,Integer>();
 SortedMap<String, Integer> newMap= new TreeMap<>(doubleCount);
 Map<String,Integer> newDouble40 = newMap.subMap("0","40");
```

In your case `Keys` are `String` so you need to have `String` values in `subMap("0","40")`. `0` is the starting key and "40" is the ending key. Your `newDouble40` has element which has a key in between `0` and `40`.

Here you can use `headMap()` as `newMap.headMap("40")`. now you will get elements which has a key less than `40`.

Eg:

```
 Map<String, Integer> doubleCount= new HashMap<>();
 doubleCount.put("c",1);
 doubleCount.put("d",2);
 doubleCount.put("a",1);
 doubleCount.put("b",4);
 SortedMap<String, Integer> newMap= new TreeMap<>(doubleCount);//sorted now
 Map<String,Integer> map1 = newMap.subMap("a", "c");
 Map<String,Integer> map2 = newMap.headMap("c");
 System.out.println(map1);
 System.out.println(map2);
```

Out put:

```
 {a=1, b=4}
 {a=1, b=4}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, Im past that error, but my issue persists, please see my answer below-

Answer (score 0):

Main issue here is that you're trying to use methods of a subinterface (java.util.SortedMap), the interface Map doesn't expose either headMap(...) or subMap(...) methods.

A correct code that will compile would be:

```
 SortedMap<String, Integer> doubleCount = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

 Map<String, Integer> newDoubleCount = doubleCount.headMap("40");
```

One thing you should consider is what is that the methods of the SortedMap returns a portion of the map based on the key argument, compared with the keys in the map, unless you know what is the value of the key of the 40th element, you can't use these methods.